# How can I make a heatmap with a large matrix?

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a 1000*1000 matrix (which only includes integer 0 and 1), but when I tried to make a heatmap, an error occurs because it is too large.

How can I create a heatmap with such a large matrix?

Comment: Plenty of answers about heatmap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789549/display-a-matrix-including-the-values-as-a-heatmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035491/how-to-put-black-borders-in-heatmap-in-r Try searching `[r] heatmap`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error. 1000x1000 shouldn't produce a distance matrix too large for R.

Comment: @Roman but this is neither of those questions...

Comment: There is advice in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) about R memory management. If you can't allocated a 1000 by 1000 image, then you should probably stop trying to do stats on your mobile phone.

Comment: Try `image(m)` after doing whatever re-ordering on rows and cols needed ?

Comment: Posted a solution using heatmap3, which is more memory efficient, especially through it's use of the fastcluster package to do the hierarchical clustering; adding argument useRaster=TRUE also helps

Answer (score 18):

I can believe that the heatmap is, at least, taking a long time, because `heatmap` does a lot of fancy stuff that takes extra time and memory.  Using `dat` from @bill_080's example:

```
## basic command: 66 seconds
t0 <- system.time(heatmap(dat))
## don't reorder rows & columns: 43 seconds
t1 <- system.time(heatmap(dat,Rowv=NA))
## remove most fancy stuff (from ?heatmap): 14 seconds
t2 <- system.time( heatmap(dat, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="column",
             main = "heatmap(*, NA, NA) ~= image(t(x))"))
## image only: 13 seconds
t3  <- system.time(image(dat))
## image using raster capability in R 2.13.0: 1.2 seconds
t4 <- system.time(image(dat,useRaster=TRUE))
```

You might want to consider what you really want out of the heatmap -- i.e., do you need the fancy dendrogram/reordering stuff?

Answer (score 11):

No errors when I try it.  Here's the code:

```
 library(lattice)

 #Build the data
 nrowcol <- 1000
 dat <- matrix(ifelse(runif(nrowcol*nrowcol) > 0.5, 1, 0), nrow=nrowcol)

 #Build the palette and plot it
 pal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"), space = "rgb")
 levelplot(dat, main="1000 X 1000 Levelplot", xlab="", ylab="", col.regions=pal(4), cuts=3, at=seq(0,1,0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to go up to about a 2300X2300 plot.  A 2400X2400 plot gave "Error using packet 1 cannot allocate vector of size 22.0 Mb" at the levelplot() statement.

Comment: For me this only worked for larger matrices with option useRaster=TRUE, ie levelplot(dat, main="1000 X 1000 Levelplot", xlab="", ylab="", col.regions=pal(4), cuts=3, at=seq(0,1,0.5), useRaster=TRUE) ; otherwise even with a 5000 x 5000 matrix it would end up allocating about 6 Gb of memory - not good!!

Comment: Plus this is a levelplot, not a heatmap with row and/or column hierarchical clustering included, which makes a big difference...

Answer (score 8):

try the **raster** package, it can handle huge raster file.

Answer (score 5):

Using `heatmap3`, which is more memory efficient than the default `heatmap` function and faster through it's use of the `fastcluster` package to do the hierarchical clustering works fine for me. Adding argument `useRaster=TRUE` also helps :

```
library(heatmap3)
nrowcol <- 1000
dat <- matrix(ifelse(runif(nrowcol*nrowcol) > 0.5, 1, 0), nrow=nrowcol)
heatmap3(dat,useRaster=TRUE)
```

[image]

The `useRaster=TRUE` seems quite important to keep memory use within limits. You can use the same argument in `heatmap.2`. Calculating the distance matrix for the hierarchical clustering is the main overhead in the calculation, but `heatmap3` uses the more efficient `fastcluster` package for that for large matrices. [With very large matrices you will unavoidably get into trouble though trying to do a distance-based hierarchical cluster.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984940/clustering-very-large-dataset-in-r) In that case you can still use arguments `Rowv=NA` and `Colv=NA` to suppress the row and column dendrograms and use some other logic to sort your rows and columns, e.g.

```
nrowcol <- 5000
dat <- matrix(ifelse(runif(nrowcol*nrowcol) > 0.5, 1, 0), nrow=nrowcol)
heatmap3(dat,useRaster=TRUE,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA)
```

still runs without problems on my laptop with 8 Gb memory, whereas with the dendrograms included it already starts to crunch.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use heatmap.2 from the gplots package and simply turn off dendrograms, as these normally take up the most computation time (from my experience).

Also, have you considered directly printing your heatmap to a file via pdf(), png() or jpeg()?